# React Router ComponentDidMount Not Executing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

I need to have the componentDidMount method to fire when the Router mounts a component so that a timeout can be started. This timeout eventually sets the state so it can't be initialized in any render lifecycles or the constructor. I tried changing the Route's `component={Home}` to `render={<Home>}`, but then the error `render is not a function` comes up. I'm really not sure why this is happening so any help would be greatly appreciated!

App.js render method:

```js
render() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Navbar />
      <Container>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
        </Switch>
      </Container>       
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Home.js:

```js
const Home = (props) => {
  const images = [ /* Stuff */ ];

  return (
    <Stack gap={4}>
      <div>
        <Card>
          <Card.Header>
            <ImageRotator images={images} />
          </Card.Header>
          <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title>// A Title</Card.Title>
            <Card.Text>
              // Text
            </Card.Text>
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>
      </div>
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

ImageRotator.js:

```js
class ImageRotator extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      firstImageIndex: 0,
      renderImages: false,
      imagesShowing: [],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const imagesShowing = this.calculateImagesToShow(this.state.firstImageIndex);
    this.setState({ imagesShowing: imagesShowing });

    window.addEventListener('resize', () => { 
      const imagesToShow = this.calculateImagesToShow(this.state.firstImageIndex);
      const imageTimeout = setTimeout(() => this.incrementImageIndex(), 5000);
      this.setState({ imagesShowing: imagesToShow, imageTimeout: imageTimeout });
    });
  }

  calculateImagesToShow(firstImageIndex) {
    // Returns the images to render on screen
  }

  resetImageInterval() {
    clearTimeout(this.state.imageInterval);
    this.setState({ imageInterval: setTimeout(() => this.incrementImageIndex(), 5000) });
  }

  incrementImageIndex() {
    // Increments the state's first image index
  }

  decrementImageIndex() {
    // Decrements the state's first image index
  }

  render() {
    // Renders the calculated images on the screen including two buttons
    // which when clicked on call the increment and decrement image index functions
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `componentDidMount` of `ImageRotator` isn't being called when it's mounted by `Home` when the route matches? `render={<Home>}` fails because the `render` prop is expecting a function that returns JSX, not a JSX literal. It's unclear what your issue/question is. Can you explain in more detail and provide reproduction steps.

Comment: I've also used ```render={() => <Home>}``` which doesn't throw that error but componentDidMount isn't getting called either. Yes, I'm sure it's not being called because I put a console.log() statement in it and a breakpoint in the Chrome devtools. The reproduction steps is just to open "localhost:3000" which defaults to the Home Route.

Comment: I see no reason at all why, or how, `componentDidMount` wouldn't/couldn't be called in `ImageRotator` ***other than*** the `ImageRotator` component not being mounted. See this *running* [codesandbox](react-router-componentdidmount-not-executing) running `react-router-dom` v4.3.1, as you can see, there's a console log in `componentDidMount` in `ImageRotator` that logs as expected. Could you try creating a codesandbox of your own that reproduces the issue that we can inspect and debug live?

Comment: Wow, sorry, epic fail on posting link on my part. Here's the working link: https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-tdd-msfg2?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @DrewReese I'm not exactly sure what changed but after I started adding stuff to that link it is now working as expected. I'll keep that codesandbox.io link in my mind next time I create a question because it's very helpful. Thank you for your help!